# What type of insulation is this?

Tags: insulation, asbestos

Planning to get this tested for asbestos, but on a cursory glance, is it apparent what variety of loose fill insulation this might be?

[image: Attic loose fill]

Comment: The asbestos crystals have hooks that make them very difficult for cilia to move. Most other materials can be cleared from sinus and lungs by cilia, with time.

Comment: Alright, but what's really, really not correct is a) panicking over asbestos, and b) thinking other mineral wools are all that much safer.  The main reason full-time workers aren't getting all manner of problems from modern materials has more to do with modern understandings of PPE.  If people had used PPE with asbestos since 1880, there'd never have been a problem.  But we're not talking about particularly dangerous here, either.  Asbestos kills people who handled it without PPE everyday as their job for 20 years.  It's not plutonium.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably rockwool or mineral wool.

Comment: Thanks. I was assuming something along those lines but comparing to online pics, mine seem have more glassy fibers/strands.